# Can we Use Exclusion-Inclusion Principle for a Countably Infinite Set?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A popular question in Mathematics is that: What percent of Counting Numbers are divisible by 3?

Without thinking twice, one might answer 33 percent.

An Extension of this is the question: What percentage of Counting Numbers are divisible by 3 or 5?

To solve this problem, others usually used Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

However, references always indicate that Exclusion-Inclusion Principle must be done in a finite set.

My question is: Is Exclusion-Inclusion Principle valid for a countably infinite set? Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: Think of it this way. Every $15$ numbers, there must be $7$, and only $7$, numbers which are divisible by $3$ or $5$. How many $15$s are there in the naturals? So the percentage of that is $\frac{7}{15}$

Comment: Thanks @AspiringMat. Based from your comment, you are suggesting that it is possible? Or can I restrict my set as 1, 2, 3, ... 15n. Where n is large

Comment: I got your point now @MattSamuel. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MattSamuel The way I understood the question is, if for sufficiently large $n$, I pick an $x$ such that $15n<x<15(n+1)$. Then the percentage of number from $1$ to $x$ that are divisible by $3$ or $5$ is approximately $7/15$ as $n$ tends to infinity. I don't see a reason to be rude in the comments. You could politely disagree or perhaps ask me to make myself more clear. Have a nice day!

Comment: No, inclusion-exclusion is not valid for infinite sets

Comment: What happens for two or more infinite sets is the cardinality of the union is the same as the cardinality of the largest of the sets in the union operation. This obviously isn't true for finite sets.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in \mathbb N$ let $P(n)$ be the number of $m\in \mathbb N$ that do not exceed $n$ and are NOT divisible by $3$ nor by $5.$

Let $15a+b=n$ where $0\leq a\in \mathbb N$ and $b\in  \mathbb Z$ with $0\leq b\leq 14.$ It is, I hope, obvious that $$P(15a)=(1-1/3)(1-1/5)15a=(8/15)15a\geq (8/15)(n-14).$$ And that $$P(15a+15)=(1-1/3)(1-1/5)P(15a+15)=(8/15)(15a+15)\leq (8/15)(n+15).$$ Since $P(15a)\leq P(n)\leq P(15a+15)$ we have $$(8/15)(1-14/n)\leq P(n)/n\leq (8/15)(1+15/n).$$ So $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-P(n)/n)=7/15.$

Comment: OP was asking about inclusion-exclusion, which is strictly for cardinality, not limits as n approaches infinity (these are still finite, after all!). The number of integers not divisible by 3 nor 5 has the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$ itself.